# How can I create a database for my site from excel/google sheets?

Tags: database, excel, google-sheets

I have created a datasheet of fashion stores, (where they are based, what they sell) and I want to be able to add a searchable database to my website where my visitors can search this data so they can find exactly what it is they want.

I know about creating websites but nothing about databases? Is there a relatively easy way to do this... I'm pretty sure what I'm asking for is quite simple. I have found paid for web apps but I really don't want to pay £20 a month...

I have both an excel sheet and google sheet. And I just want my visitors to be able to search through store location, the items they want, etc.. its all just text search.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to consider SQL or MySQL for these sort of operations.